# Numpy attributes not recognized in Numba

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, jit, numba

Numba offers JIT for Python. In its documentation it says "One objective of Numba is having a seamless integration with NumPy."

So why including some of the simplest features from numpy isn't possible:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import *

@jit(nopython=True)
def testfun(x):
  y = np.size(x)
  return y

x=np.array([1 ,2, 3],dtype=float)
testfun(x)
```

When I run this code, I get the error "Unknown attribute 'size' of type Module," which means attribute 'size' is not recognized.

Numba understands calls to NumPy ufuncs. I assume simple numpy functions such as size, shape, sum, reshape, etc are ufuncs. Of course, removing '
(nopython=True)' works, but that falls it back to the slow run with  pyobjects.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.size`.  It isn't a `ufunc`.  It either returns `x.size` or `x.shape(axis)`.  It's in the `fromnumeric.py` file, which suggests that it is legacy code - from the old `numeric` package.  There are a lot of `numpy` functions that delegate the action to array methods.

Answer (score 4):

The following works:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def testfun(x):
    y = x.size
    return y
```

Certain attributes are supported, but you should look at when the corresponding function is:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#attributes

The documentation is pretty complete regarding what parts of numpy numba supports.

Comment: Great! Althought I am using other functions (reshape, matmul ...) for which the error persists. But thanks for the link, which clarifies.